# Define a dynamic 'basePath' environmental variable without the locale

Tags: config, multi-environment, environmentvariables

So in my general config file I've defined an environmental variable called basePath (as per the [Environment-Specific Variables documentation](https://craftcms.com/docs/multi-environment-configs#environment-specific-variables)). I'm using the [getcwd()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getcwd.php) function to get the working directory.

```
return array(
    '*' => array(
        'environmentVariables' => array(
            'basePath' => getcwd(),
        )
    ),
);
```

I'm using this for a few reasons:

1. I work in an environment where many people can be working on the same project at the same time. So their local basePath is always different.
2. My different [siteUrls](https://craftcms.com/docs/config-settings#siteUrl) for my setup use trailing locales in the url: `'siteUrl' => array( 'en' => 'http://www.website.com/', 'fi' => 'http://www.website.com/fi/' )`. So when it comes to targeting environment-specific locales, things get messy.
3. `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` is ok locally, but fails on a live server.

**So my problem is** when using `getcwd()`, the locale is included in path. Is there a way to trim this out dynamically?

Or is there a way to strip out the current locale from this path on-the-fly? `rtrim(getcwd(),"fi")`

Maybe there is a more reliable way to get the working directory?

Answer (score 1):

Check out [craft-multi-environment](https://github.com/nystudio107/craft-multi-environment); even if you don't use it, you might crib some of the ideas from it.

For instance, how the [basePath is determined](https://github.com/nystudio107/craft-multi-environment/blob/master/example.env.php#L49).